# Codeigniter jquery search tutorial

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, search

Can you guys suggest me a good codeigniter search tutorial having functionalities like http://myfav.es/settings/sites/#/all-sites/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a jquery plugin like [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/), it has a add-on to [filter](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering) (either by table or per column).

[Example here.](http://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)

Comment: Thanks Rooneyl... Let me try this... Did you know any other method which is relevant to codeigniter?

Comment: if you are using datatables don't forget to use ignitedDatatables CI library will make you life really easy https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables

Comment: Thanks umefarooq. Do you have any tutorial for datatables to work with codeigniter. Coz both frameworks are new to me. (I'm creating a simple search in codeigniter similar to http://myfav.es/settings/sites/#/all-sites/ If you have any other to do this idea please let me know.)